# Auto attachment file for email service c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have generated a PDF file from my gridview. My task is to send the PDF file that I have generated to a specific email without the user to use the upload control and select the PDF file I generated. I am able to do the normal email with the user manually browse and select the PDF as attachment. Is there a way to achieve the auto attachment of a PDF file to the email?

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT Id, msgContent, msgDate from Message where msgDate between '" + dateFrom + "' and '" + dateTo + "'";
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

This my data binding to the gridview.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        using (MemoryStream ObjememoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ObjememoryStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlworker.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            byte[] Filebytes = ObjememoryStream.ToArray();
            ObjememoryStream.Close();
            using (MemoryStream inputData = new MemoryStream(Filebytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream outputData = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    string PDFFileword = txtPassword.Text;//you can also generate Dynamic word  
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputData);
                    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, outputData, true, PDFFileword, PDFFileword, PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
                    Filebytes = outputData.ToArray();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(Filebytes);
                    Response.End();
                    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the way I generate the PDF file.

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, txtTo.Text))
        {
            mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            mm.Body = txtBody.Text;
            if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
            }
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
        }
```

This is the way I am sending email by upload control the attachment file. "fuAttachment" is the ID of my upload control, is there a way to make the attachment became automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create new `Attachment` instance and add it to the collection of attatchments in mailmessage instance like this.

if you have file physically stored on hard drive and you know the path then:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment("FILE_PATH", 
                     MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

if you have byte array in memory then:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

if you have stream then:

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: Attachment attachment = new Attachment("C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\GridViewExport",
                     MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mm.Attachments.Add(attachment);                                                             Thank you sir, but I got this error as Unrecognized escape sequence for the \ within the path.

Comment: You need to specify **@** ahead of path. like `@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\GridViewExport"‌​`

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\GridViewExport'.'                                                           I got an error says that It couldn't find the file                                       C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads,this is my file location and the file name GridViewExport is correct

Comment: if your file is a `.pdf` then use `@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\GridViewExport.pdf"`. It should be the exact file path with the file name and extension.

Comment: Lol, how stupid am I to forgot I have to put the extension too for this file name. Thanks for help sir, big thanks for you 2 gentleman.